# mongoose find() data error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find, database

what am i doing wrong?,
i want to get the name from the teams.
when i use teamData.name (this should work i think) i get undefined.
in the model Team name ofcourse exist.

***code***:

```
userRoutes.get('/wait', function (req, res) {
    Kwizz.findOne({_id: req.session.kwizzId}, function (err, kwizzData) {
        Team.find({_id: {$in: kwizzData.teams}}, function(err, teamData) {
            console.log("team name:  " + teamData.name);
            res.json(teamData);
        });
    });
});
```

***result***:
team name:  undefined

Comment: With `find`, `teamData` is an array of `Team` docs, not just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting array of collections

```
for(var i = 0;i<teamData.length;i++)
{
 console.log("team name:  " + teamData[i].name);
}
```

Comment: i was just thinking about that after that sharp comment from JohnnyHK, thnx for this posting it!